# JavaScript, проблема с SetInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Подскажите, почему без if-а таймер работает нормально, а с ним - вообще не запускается?

```
var sum = 0;
var first = 0;
var second = 0;

function additionFunction() {
  document.getElementById('example').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('timerAddition').innerHTML = "";
  first = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  second = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  if (right >= 1) {
    first = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15);
    second = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15);
  }
  sum = parseInt(first + second);
  document.getElementById('example').innerHTML = first.toString() + " + " + second.toString();
  document.getElementById('timerAddition').innerHTML = sum + Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
  timerAddition();
}

var timerID = setInterval(timerAddition, 1000);

function timerAddition() {
  var obj = document.getElementById('timerAddition');
  obj.innerHTML--;

  if (obj.innerHTML < sum.innerHTML) {
    clearInterval(timerID);
  }
}
```

Comment: Добавьте разметку html и откуда у числового значения `sum` вдруг innerHTML взялся?

Comment: если я не ошибаюсь, у вас obj.innerHTML воспринимается как текст, попробуйте везде, где он есть прописать +obj.innerHTML вместо obj.innerHTML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> obj.innerHTML < sum.innerHTML
> ```

Потому что тут вместо чисел сравниваются строки. Можно попробовать так:

```
+obj.innerHTML < +sum.innerHTML
```

но вообще плохо деражать данные в разметке.

Comment: так таймер идет, но до if-а не доходит. А этот sum = parseInt(first + second); Сума двух чисел. Может, чтобы лучше понять что к чему, можна глянуть вот сюда: http://kurusa.zhecky.net/lesson_11/. Была бы вам очень признательна за помощь

Comment: @Біпач, а `sum` откуда взялось? В твоём коде его нет.

Comment: это глобальная переменная, которая используется в немного большой функции. Сейчас добавлю.

Comment: вот, сверху, в комментарий не помещается.